# Force an app to be "compatible" with windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, compatibility

there are a lot of programs that check upon running if you are running the right version of windows (specifically for me the uninstall program for my Brother Printer software).

Having windows 8 the installer tells me it will not run because I have the wrong version of windows. However the software installed just fine and runs just fine so it should in theory just be able to uninstall.

Compatibility mode set to Windows 7 does not do the trick.

Is there a way to tell the installer that I am using windows 7?

Thanks for your ideas and suggestions guys :).

EDIT: This is the specific error code: IS015- GetOsVersion - 1

Comment: Do you get a specific error message? And what model printer exactly. Maybe there are compatible drivers you could install over the top, then uninstall. Maybe you could try something like this: http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/Other-DRIVERS-TOOLS/Brother/Brother-MFC-8710DW-Printer-Uninstall-Tool-10100.shtml

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Added the error to the post. Also unfortunately that is not for my printer and just remove the drivers not the software.

Comment: If it uses an MSI for install or uninstall, you could possibly use ORCA the MSI editor to remove the check, though the tool is no longer supported and *may* not work with the latest msi files.

Comment: @GrahamWager nope no .MSI, only setup.exe :(

Comment: Some installers may have a `--force` type option available from the command line

Answer (score 6):

Chances are good that what is happening is that you are setting the compatibility mode for the wrong thing. In the old days, installers were a single, simple executable file that runs to install and/or uninstall the software, but these days, installers are elaborate frameworks (e.g., Windows Installer, InstallShield, etc.) As such, what might be happening is that the uninstall executable you set the compatibility mode for may be running another file somewhere else which is causing the problem.

What you need to do is to find out the actual executable that is giving you the *wrong OS* error and set *that* file’s compatibility mode. This may or may not be easy depending on what installer method is being used.

For starters, let’s assume a simple `exe⇨exe` architecture:

1. Re-run the uninstaller
2. When you are confronted with the error, bring up the Task Manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shfit</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>)
3. Switch to the *Applications* tab
4. Locate the installer in the list
5. Right-click it and select *Go To Process*
   (What file is being indicated? Hopefully it is a specific file as opposed to `msiexec.exe` because that would make it a harder to fix/hack.)
6. Right-click the process name and select *Properties*
7. Set the compatibility settings in the *Compatibility* tab
8. Re-run the unisntaller

If you do not see the uninstaller’s window in the *Applications* tab, then you will need another tool like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find out the executable file giving the error (on the bright side, ProcExp makes it easy to see the chain of processes by showing them in a tree).

If it turns out that the program in question is using Windows Installer, then you will need to modify its `.msi` file to [edit the OS dependency](https://www.google.com/search?q=msi%20os%20check). Microsoft’s tool [Orca](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255905?wa=wsignin1.0) is useful for this.

Comment: it only references setup.exe unfortunately... there aren't any other executable files around. Even running it without any arguments (uninstall instructions) does not get it to run...

Comment: I'll have to wait for an update I guess... Anyway, thanks for your ideas!

Comment: *What* references `setup.exe`? *Which* `setup.exe`? Are you sure `setup.exe` isn’t launching another file?

Comment: I launch setup manually. No other files are executed or referenced

Comment: *> I launch setup manually.*   You mean you navigate to the folder and double-click `setup.exe`? Then that may be your problem; the uninstaller may not work like that and require command-line arguments or shared-memory variables or something.

Comment: I know, "unninstall" in the start menu adds arguments but in both cases the problem remains the same.